Studying stability of pde
I have a problem with studying the stability of this PDE.
$$U_t = U_{xx} + f(U).$$
Let $U^{*}(x)$ be a solution for this equation. As conditions we have ${U^{*}}'(x) > 0$ for $x < x_{0}$, ${U^{*}}'(x)<0$ for $x>x_{0}$, and $U^{*}(x)$ tends exponentially fast to zero as $|x|\rightarrow 0$.
Now I linearized the equation and found after putting $V+U^{*}=U$:
$$
V_t = V_{xx} + Df(U^{*})V.
$$
To continue solving I've been asked to show that ${U^{*}}'(x)$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue equal to zero.
Can any one provide me with the steps, please?

Hello and welcome to MSE. I strongly encourage you to use MathJax to improve readability of your post and assist contributors in understanding it.

Would you be able to elaborate which operator we should consider the eigenfunction with respect to?

Unfortunately they didn't specify.. I'd appreciate if u provide me with the solution or the idea ..

If $U^*(x)$ is a solution to the original PDE and depends only on $x$, then it satisfies the steady-state equation $U^*_{xx} + f(U^*) = 0$. Differentiating this equation w.r.t. $x$ yields
$$
(U^*_x)_{xx} + Df(U^*)U^*_x=0.
$$
Therefore $U^*_x$ is an eigenfunction of the operator $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + Df(U^*)$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Thank you so much , that was so helpful. If you don't Mind , would you explain how I continue to study the stability . Well I know that the solution is unstable but I didn't know how to prove it

If the operator $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + Df(U^*)$ has any spectrum with positive real part then the solution is unstable. With only a zero eigenvalue, the situation is more complicated. This note set and the included references may be helpful https://depts.washington.edu/bdecon/workshop2012/g_stability.pdf

I didn't understand why  the eigenvalue equals to zero !!

Because the operator applied to $U_x^$ equals zero. If $U_x^\neq0$ then this is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue zero
